# How to draw png using image buffer via python API

Tags: python, scripting

To draw an image in the viewport, we can use the built-in shader with the `bpy.data.image` data block
See the template:  https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html

The disadvantage is that the user can access the data block. Imagine that there are many pngs to draw, which will cause trouble for the user.

So how to draw them using `imbuf` module from a external filepath instead of loading them into data blocks

```
import bpy, imbuf

img_path = 'D:\\xx\\img.png'
imgbuf = imbuf.load(img_path)
..

def draw():
    ..

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

Thank you for your attention.